# Are there any Pickit 3 clones available?

Tags: pic

I've Googled around and came across quite a few Pickit 2 clones, but I'm looking for the newer Pickit 3. I'm looking for schematics, firmware/.hex files for building a Pickit **3** to save some costs.

Are there any Pickit 3 clone, community projects out there?

Comment: @Madmanguruman That's rather rude, and I wasn't born yesterday, so yes, I did Google. Please don't participate in this question, if you can't provide constructive advice. I hava a firm belief, that people that tell others to "Google It" are the ones who don't have the answers. Please spare us wasting your energy like that.

Answer (score 2):

Best be verifying the firmware (non-Microchip) is legal to possess and use.

**Comments not directly related to your question:**

After peeking around a bit, a clone can run you about $30USD (http://www.ebay.com/itm/Clone-Microchip-Development-Programmer-Mini-PICKIT-3-/350637699036?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item51a3a2afdc).   A few more searches can turn up clone Pickit 3’s in the $20 arena.

Here is a review of one: (http://dangerousprototypes.com/2011/12/19/sure-electronics-pickit-3-clone-review/)

A **real one** (http://www.ebay.com/itm/ICSP-Adapter-ZIF-18-20A-w-PICkit-3-USB-Programmer-/330401312866?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ced73f062) can be had for about $58USD.  (I’ve purchased from J1SYS and can vouch for his credibility but I’m not a paid representative and I didn’t stay in the fancy hotel last night.)

The advantage of a clone is the price of course.  The advantage of purchasing the real thing is Microchip updates WILL properly and correctly burn to the real Pickit device, apparently not guaranteed with a clone.

$28 difference between the two examples.   If you’re burning one or ten chips, might be better to check locally, maybe someone will burn them for you.   (Though I don’t do it anymore {I’m disabled now and don’t get around like I used to} for one specific forum, I’ve burned chips for complete strangers on both U.S. coasts, far north as the Canadian border and pert near the Mexican border in Texas.  They email me the .hex file, I burn the chip, they Paypal the price of the chip and postage – the burning I’ve always done for free.)      If you plan on burning more than ten, I’d look at spending the extra $28 (about $60 + shipping) and get the real deal.  Honest.

The final points are:

-many of the clones are incapable of in-circuit-debugging, a sweet option!!
-how much scrounging and cobbling together justifies a $60USD already assembled, real deal?
-troubleshooting firmware is one thing, troubleshooting the firmware you've coded PLUS troubleshooting the imitation programming hardware too, well, doesn't sound very productive (or much fun) to me.  :)

Comment: Can you keep your instructions on how to Google to yourself? Online searching in this situation was about 95% of the effort I took to try and find the required resources, the rest was allocated to asking an honest question on StackExchange. The reason I came here to ask is because my attempts to find resources online turned out in results that deemed unreliable, in a different language, partial, outdated or unclear. Sometimes we need real people to answer stupid questions like mine, pity these are becoming lesser by the day.

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk  I apologize, I didn’t mean to get you all riled up and I definitely did not mean to offend you.    If I had not posted those Google searches, I would be **assuming** you have, or lack, vital information you need to make a reasonably intelligent decision.   Your question isn’t stupid and deserves a legitimate answer, that’s why I followed up with __“Comments not directly related to your question:”__

Comment: No offense taken. I appreciate your answer, and the time you have taken to contribute to assisting me. I'm currently looking at the BOM costing for building a PicKit 3 clone, using Microchips unmodified firmware. It is looking likely, that it would be more feasible to just go and buy the thing...less painful that way too I guess.

Comment: Joe, don't use LMGTFY. It's unnecessarily rude behavior. If you're looking for a better way of phrasing it, consider the phrase "Try the following search terms in google".

Comment: Yes W5VO, I see now the error in my ways.   Thank you.

Comment: Having the correct tools is paramount in driving a project to a successful completion.   Building your own clone programmer would be an excellent learning experience, if that is your goal.   Having the “real deal” sets you on the right path for accomplishing the “productive” projects you have in mind.   The Pickit 3 is just a tool, albeit an invaluable tool in the arsenal of the creative individual.   I hope your excitement is as great as mine when the postman delivered my first and each successive Pickit!!!   Create and invent josef.van.niekerk!!   :)

Comment: @W5VO  Thank you for taking care of the LMGTFY boo boo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PicKit 3 Schematic available at [this forum post at edaboard.com](http://www.edaboard.com/thread199055.html) and the schematics have also been released by Microchip, and is available on page 65 & 66 on the [PicKit 3 User Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PICkit_3_User_Guide_51795A.pdf)

The Edaboard board layout is not 100% complete, it looks like components have been placed, but routing would need to be done.

The firmware can be downloaded from the [Pickit 3 product page](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en538340&redirects=pickit3), look for the link at the bottom of the page: **PICkit3 Programmer Application and Scripting Tool v3.10**

Answer (score -1):

There is a web page that documents the entire process of making your own pickit 3. It has full project documents including design files and photos and explanations of the build process. You can see it here:

[Pickit 3 DIY](http://Reviahh.wordpress.com)